# Which version of apache ant is compatible with OS X 10.7.5?

Tags: xcode, bash, apache, ant, terminal

I've had so much trouble in installing ant. I first downloaded it from the apache website, had some errors. Then I finally figured out a way to install through terminals 'brew install ant'; which it worked after downloading Xcode and configuring bash_profile.

So my question is, why does it show that the version is 1.8.2? instead of 1.9.7? Is this a compatibility issue?

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEAJX.png)

Comment: What is output of `echo $ANT_HOME`?

Comment: It doesnt output  anything.. its weird!

Comment: `echo $PATH`? Looks like PATH variable has 1.8.2 assigned...can you add location where you downloaded newer ant version and also content of `.bash_profile` file

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, All OS X versions prior to 10.9 have ANT already installed. From 10.9 and later , we need to install ANT.
Installation ANT is about extracting tar file, setting ANT_HOME variable, Setting path and setting JAVA_HOME as well.

In my view, you are already seeing an older version of ANT installed in your machine by default. However, ANT 1.8.x or 1.9.x both are pretty stable and should able to meet your build automation objectives.

Comment: Ive tried using 'echo $ANT_HOME' but it doesnt print anything.. can you please explain how to set the ant_home and java_home ?